# Storing RSA keys in a clustered authentication service

Tags: authentication, jwt, rsa, cluster-computing, hmac

I want to build an authentication service that uses JWT with signatures generated using RS256. In a single-server solution, the implementation is rather straightforward. However, when it comes to making it multi-node there are two related issues to which I'm not finding clear answers:

1. In a cluster solution, should every server use its own key pair or can a shared key pair be used by multiple nodes? In that case how to build efficiently a JWK that doesn't contain too many keys?
2. On the other hand, if sharing the private key is possible without incurring major security issues, which is the best approach to share the key and manage its rotation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If possible (IMO) you should use a single private key for signing access tokens.

Having multiple would just increase complexity (e.g. the back-end resource servers would need logic to work out what public key to use for JWT validation, or cycle through multiple public keys to validate a JWT) and I don't really see any security benefit.

FWIW there might be business reasons for needing to support multiple on the back-end e.g. if your company has multiple products with separate auth tenants/sign-on-domains you might need to support multiple keys in shared back-end services/capabilities - for this type of scenario you'd need to use something such as the token issuer (`iss`) claim to determine what public key to use for JWT validation.

WRT rotating keys; if you're using a PaaS IDP like Auth0 it's all probably handled for you. If you're using a COTS product like Keycloak (or if you've rolled your own IDP) you'll need to have multiple public keys defined in your JWKS endpoint (albeit temporarily). The new key would be designated as 'active' and would be used for signing all subsequent tokens, whereas the old one would be designated as 'passive' and is only needed to verify access tokens that were issued prior to the rotation and are not yet expired. *Note: once all access tokens signed using the old key are expired, you can probably decommission/remove the old key.*

[Here's a link](https://wjw465150.gitbooks.io/keycloak-documentation/content/server_admin/topics/realms/keys.html#_rotating_keys) to Keycloak documentation about rotating keys that might be useful.

In your back-end services where you do JWT validation, the public key corresponding to the key ID (`kid`) claim on the JWTs should be cached. If a request is signed with the new private key the JWT should have a different key ID. If a back-end service encounters a new key ID, it should lazily go back to the JWKS endpoint to get the public key associated to the new key ID (and this should then be cached as well).

In most common programming languages there are libraries that handle most of this for you e.g. I've done JWT validation in .NET Core using the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication package and all I needed to do was configure an Open ID matadata endpoint (which references the JWKS endpoint) and things like key rotating & caching was all handled transparently.

Comment: Hi Ryan, thanks for the explanation. I need to clarify one point I think: I'm building an authentication service that might need to scale on multiple machines. Then the traffic should be load-balanced. If I need to scale my auth service (which is responsible to sign tokens) using the architecture I just described, how should I deal with the private key (if I don't want to rely on external services)? Should I pass the same private key among the various nodes (obviously using encrypted communication)? Or should I use independent keys for each node. Can you clarify this point?

Comment: Technically you *could* have a different key pair (private/public key set) per authorization server node. If you go with this approach. each and every public key would need to be defined in the JWKS endpoint with a corresponding Key ID (kid), so that back-end services can work out the correct public key to use for JWT validation. Personally I would just use the same key pair across all nodes. Like I said, I don't really see any security benefit of having multiple (aside from key rotation, which is temporary) - it doesn't lessen the impact if/when one of the private keys is compromised.

Comment: ... so I looked at the JWKS endpoints for some Auth0 tenants as well as Azure AD. The Auth0 tenants I looked at all have 2 keys defined, whereas AAD has 7 !... I'm not actually sure why... I found this SO - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43978673/why-does-aws-cognito-use-multiple-public-keys-for-jwts - which talks about AWS Cognito having 2 keys as well (like Auth0). It's suggested that 1 is for ID tokens and 1 is for access tokens... still doesn't explain why AAD has 7...